# When I run a program in another computer a method is not called

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing a WPF app with .NET Framework 4.6.2, Entity Framework 6.13 and C#.

I have compiled the app in Debug\Any CPU and also in Debug\x86. In both cases the same executable doesn't work properly in a second computer. On my development machine works fine, and in the second one it doesn't run a method.

I have this problem when I select an item from a `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxTrzType" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,25,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25" ItemsSource="{Binding TrzTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding TrzTypeSelectedItem}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And this the property:

```
public TrzType TrzTypeSelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return trzTypeSelectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
            log.Debug("TrzTypeSelectedItem: NULO");
        else
            log.DebugFormat("TrzTypeSelectedItem: {0}", value.Legislation);

        if (value != trzTypeSelectedItem)
        {
            log.Debug("TrzTypeSelectedItem changed");

            trzTypeSelectedItem = value;

            if (value != null)
            {
                log.Debug("TrzTypeSelectedItem value no NULL");

                LoadProductsByLaw(trzTypeSelectedItem.Legislation);

                log.Debug("TrzTypeSelectedItem after load");
            }

            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("TrzTypeSelectedItem");
        }
    }
}
```

And the method is never run:

```
private void LoadProductsByLaw(LawTypes law)
{
    log.Debug("LoadProductsByLaw");

    List<Products> pro = null;

    PanelInfo = Resources.LoadingProducts;
    InfoPanelVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

    ConnectToCodesManager();

    pro = codeManangerClient.GetProductsByLawPublic((byte)law);

    if ((pro != null) && (pro.Count > 0))
    {
        Products = new ObservableCollection<Products>(pro);
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Products");
    }
    else
    {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            if ((Products != null) && (Products.Count > 0))
                Products.Clear();
        });
    }

    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
    {
        if ((ProductionOrders != null) && (ProductionOrders.Count > 0))
            ProductionOrders.Clear();

        if ((Batches != null) && (Batches.Count > 0))
            Batches.Clear();

        IsProductSelectEnabled = true;
        IsProductionOrderSelectEnabled = false;
        IsBatchSelectEnabled = false;

        InfoPanelVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        PanelInfo = string.Empty;
    });
}
```

Any idea about this problem?

My development machine is a:

> Windows 7 Pro Service Pack 1
>   Intel Core i7-490 @3.60GHz
>   16,0GB of RAM
>   64 bits Operating System

And the second machine where it doesn't run is a:

> Windows 7 Embedded Standard Service Pack 1
>   Intel Celeron CPU 1020E @ 2.20Hz
>   2,00 GB of RAM
>   32 bit Operating System

The logs it writes are:

```
TrzTypeSelectedItem: European
TrzTypeSelectedItem changed
TrzTypeSelectedItem value no NULL
```

But the next one should be `LoadProductsByLaw` but I don't see it in log file.

Comment: How have you determined this? I'd put many more log statements into the code to track down exactly where it's failing.

Comment: did you check with a debugger whether every `if` condition on the way is met? Do you get into the setter of `TrzTypeSelectedItem` or is it even never reached?

Comment: Check if .net 4.6.2 framework is set up on that PC

Comment: Show us your debug logs...

Comment: Does it hit the setter?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I set a lot of logs as you can see in the code. At the end of the question I have added the logs written in log file. I have run the same executable on my development PC at it works. @S.Petrosov is set up on that PC.

Comment: I have changed a dll version number and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the program was using a dll from GAC instead of using the dll in program's folder. Both dlls have the same version number.

I haven't changed the dll's version when I added more functionalities.

I changed dll version number, recompiled the program and now it works on the second computer.

I don't understand why it always gets first dlls from GAC.

Comment: To understand why it goes to the GAC first: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx#Initiating the Bind